# JavaScript - override or prevent execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a client project and I have to include their header and footer, which includes some core JavaScript files. I have a couple of `PNG`s on the page, but their core JS file is poorly coded and doesn't check for IE 7 before attempting to replace `IMG` tags that contain `.png` files with `DIVS` that use the `AlphaImageLoader` filter. The result is that in IE 7, all my `.png` images are replaced with `DIV` tags that have a default `display: block`, causing a linebreak after every single png image in my pages.

What I'd like to do is override their function with a better one or somehow prevent theirs from executing, but I cannot modify the JS file itself, which both defines the function and attaches it to the window `onload` event. I've tried redefining the function under the same name in several places (header, just before the `/body` tag, in `$(document).ready`, etc...) but the original function always seems to execute, presumably because the original function code is what is stored with the event handler, and not merely a pointer to the function.

Any way I can fix? Is there a way to selectively remove `onload` event handlers?

Comment: Are they assigning it with an event listener, or just through window.onload?

Comment: Does the JS file you are trying to override use jQuery? I think there is a solution if this is the case

Comment: Can you look inside the JS and see how it was bound? It matters.

Comment: It was bound using window.attachEvent

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only thing running at load, I think you could do

```
window.onload = null;
```

If there are other things running, I guess you'd have to reattach them. It's a little fragile, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I don't know what else is being attached, and cannot make any guarantees.

Comment: Is there a way to enumerate all attached events?

Comment: Hrm, about all I can suggest then is to fire up Firebug or something, and have a look at window.onload. There may be some obvious way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In IE7 you can use the detachEvent method:-

```
window.detachEvent("load", fn)
```

where fn is the function that was attached, however since there is jquery in this mix it may be a tall order getting hold of the actual function that was attached.  Most likely the actual function attached will be anonymous.

Comment: using 'load' threw an error, but 'onload' did not. Neither stopped the function from executing, however.

Comment: @Chris: I couldn't remember whether IE uses the "on" prefix in this case.  The reason its not working will be because the function in question is either called by another function which is attached to the event or call by a function assigned directly to the onload property.

Comment: It might help if you add a little bit of code or event a small repro of what you are trying to do to the question.

Comment: It's possible the function is being assigned anonymously or through a proxy. If it's been attached with attachEvent, detachEvent really should work for a known function. And yes IE prefixes with "on".

Answer (score 0):

A large IFRAME between header & footer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how it was bound, you might be able to get away with something like:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var alert=function(a){
    console.log(a);
  }
  window.onload();
}
```

Obviously, you'd want to redefine something other than alert, but that might work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if that's all it does, you can write a function to reverse it, look for all png images and strip away the div, and if you want to skip certain images you can implant an attribute to those you want to treat differently

another way is to trick the function by not having the png part of the image file name, and on load, append the .png (after their onload)

or maybe you can replace your png images with another tag, and replace onload

by the way, you can know exactly whats inside the onload, if you just alert window.onload, if there is nothing but that functionality, set window.onload = null;

Comment: Just FYI, setting window.onload to null doesn't work, at least for IE 7 which is the problem case. The assigned event handlers still fire.

Comment: what about window.onload = function(){ };
if that does not prevent the function, then its not onload you should fix, maybe its document.body.onload, and it may also be onload of a specific element, like an empty image...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$(window).unbind("load")`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the name of the function that replaces the PNG images? If so you might be able to override the existing function by doing something like this:

```
// Assuming PNG function is called pngSwap
function pngSwap() {
    alert('png swap');              
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.pngSwap && window.pngSwap.constructor === Function) {
        var oldFunc = window.pngSwap;
        window.pngSwap = function() {
            alert('new png swap');
        }
    }

    pngSwap();
});
```