# Programmatically disable window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to override default behavior of window.location.reload - making it a no-op, for debugging purposes?

Comment: My first guess was `window.location.reload = function() {}` but this doesn't work, at least on Firefox.

Comment: Should be possible - see [Javascript - override or prevent execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850090/javascript-override-or-prevent-execution)

Comment: `window.location.reload = function() {}` works on Firefox 4

Comment: @YiJiang
Not in _my_ Firefox 4+: `[14:27:19.242] Error: Permission denied to shadow native property`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason, `location.reload` effectively is not a writable property in Firefox and Chrome. Here's some crazy way I came up with to override it (and others) in those browsers. It uses the non-standard [`.__defineGetter__()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) method, in part to bypass the magic of `window.location = "/home.html"` from interfering.

```
var _location = location;
__defineGetter__('location', function() {
    var s = new String(_location);
    for(i in _location) (function(i) {
        s.__defineGetter__(i, function() {
            return typeof _location[i] == 'function' ? function(){} : _location[i];
        });
        s.__defineSetter__(i, function(){});
    })(i);
    return s;
});
__defineSetter__('location', function(){});
```

The resulting mock object should prevent any function call (including `.reload`) or assignment (setting `.href`) from actually taking effect. Alternatively, you can limit your testing to IE, Safari, and Opera, in which `.reload` is writable.

Comment: Won't work in Opera 11.60: "`Unhandled Error: __defineGetter__: invalid modification of non-configurable property`".

Comment: That solution doesn't seem so crazy, but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome 99.

Answer (score 3):

you have to call this code in a self-calling-function unless it won't work.

```
(function(location){
   ...
})(window.location);
```

Comment: This also fails silently in Chrome