# How to override window.location in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, window.location

I am trying to override the window.location in Firefox, through the following code and keep getting an error (actually want to prevent the default behavior, but I think that's not relevant) :

```
    Code : 
    window.__defineGetter__('location', function() {});

    Error
    redeclaration of var location
```

I started with the suggestions at [Programatically disable window.location.reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204615/programatically-disable-window-location-reload), but didn't work.

Thanks in advance, 
Sunil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `location` property of Window is non-configurable for security reasons, because some broken things out in the wild base security checks on the value of `window.location.toString()`, so you can't do this.