# Prevent JavaScript Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, onbeforeunload, window.location

I need to prevent any page redirect/reloading caused by JavaScript (e.g., `window.location.href = 'http://some.thing'` or `window.location.reload()`).
Also I need, that no prompt window is displayed for the user (like 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?')

I looked for solutions and looks like everything is changing about it. In some articles it's written, that it's possible to override `window.location`, in other articles it's said, that it's impossible. So I'm not sure about current situation for such a problem.

I tried:
- to override `window.location` object, but looks like it's impossible (as it mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990537 and as I tried in Chrome and FF).
- to use `onbeforeunload` event. It's possible to prevent reloading of a page in this way, but a prompt window is displayed for the user.

Is there any way to prevent javascript redirect/reloading w/o any prompt window?

Comment: Is the javascript redirect/reload caused by user interaction? If so preventing it without notice could confuse/frustrate the user as the result of their "click" would not be as expected. If your use case doesn't involve user input then of course my comment doesn't apply ;)

Comment: No. It's for example redirect to another page after 5 seconds.

Comment: Is this for a page where you control the source?

Comment: The page can include some core code (which I can control) and some custom code (which I can't edit and I don't know what can be there). So if you say about changing the redirect code itself, I can't do it.

Comment: But on stacjoverflow you cant execute this window.location = "hello new url", dont work and reload again the stackoverflow, how they do this?.