# Is it possible to override window.location.hostname in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious is there any possibility to override window.location.hostname?
I didn't found anything about that on google... probably I searched for wrong phrases because I think that someone had to asked it before me.

Sorry for my bad english.

EDIT:
To be more specific. I don't want to do that. I want to know if someone can override that to execute my code.

In general - I have list of domains that I approve to execute some code. When

`if (window.location.hostname === myurl.com)` gives true then they are good to go, other case they will have alert or something. I don't want someone to do something like that:

```
window.location.hostname = "myurl.com" 

if (window.location.hostname === myurl.com)
```

Comment: What u want to do, Please be specific or give an example.

Comment: In general - I check in my JS on what domain code is executed. If domain is on the list of approved domains then I let them execute code. That is why I want to know if someone can override it to something that is on my list to execute code

Comment: Did you try to set it what happened?

Comment: It didn't changed so that's good but I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985874/how-to-override-window-location-in-firefox

Comment: @SoonDead Your link get me to question which I posted here. Previously I was sure that it's not possible but I saw that someone started to mess with that so I wanted to have specific answers.

Comment: @RobertJagoda care as this is not true for all browsers, and according to your comments what you want to do is not safe in any way. Check the second edit to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location these are properties. Thus you can "set them to navigate to another URL" - however, that would result in a redirection.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted that answer because it has url to reference.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Contrary to what others tell you, it is quite simple:</s>

```
window.__defineGetter__("location", function(){
    return {
        hostname: 'malicious site'
    };
});

alert(window.location.hostname); // will alert 'malicious site'
```

As a thumb rule: every validation you do in JavaScript can be circumvented.

---

**EDIT**:

The above will fail in decent browsers, because of security reasons, but not all browsers consider security an important aspect.

Execute the following code in old IE (I did this with IE10 compatibility mode, I'm not sure which IE it tries to mimick):

```
var window = {
    location: {
        hostname: 'malicious site'
    }
};

alert(window.location.hostname);
```

It will result in `malicious site`.

I'm not sure in how many other browsers you can override `window` in the given context but it's certainly alarming.

---

**EDIT2**:

You comment to an other answer:

> I want be sure that if someone paste my JS code on site then code didn't execute if he is not on 'the list'.

You got this all wrong. Nothing prevents the user that pastes yourcode, from also modifying 'the list'! Or anything else in the JavaScript for that matter!

Your original code is this for example:

```
function isInList(hostname) {
    for (var i = 0; i < siteList.length; i++) {
      if (siteList[i] === hostname) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

if (isInList(window.location.hostname)) {
    // execute code
} else {
    // do not execute 
}
```

The user copying it can modify it to:

```
function isInList(hostname) {
    return true;
}

if (isInList(window.location.hostname)) {
    // execute code
} else {
    // do not execute 
}
```

Or

```
if (true) {
    // execute code
} else {
    // do not execute 
}
```

If the site is his, he has complete control over the javascript executed.

Comment: You're overwriting `window.hostname.location` not `window.location.hostname`.

Comment: Undeleting as an other scenario has came up.

Comment: Thanks for engage in this. Happily I doesn't have to worry about that (I think) because I give to clients code similar to google analytics - user paste code which inserts url to JS file on my server. In that JS is `if` which checks domains so they can't pass `true` because they don't have access to that file. They could only override window.location.hostname before my inserted JS file to get true. But as answers showed it's not possible.

Comment: If I wanted to steal your code, I would just download it, edit it and serve the edited one form my server. You could do nothing about it.

Comment: IE9 Quirks Mode will respond with `malicious site`. IE9 Standards Mode will not.

Comment: This not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

It's a property, not a method. I am able to change its value from the Firefox console, and it tries to load the page from a different host (http://fake.host/questions/16462082/...)

Comment: Doing that in console is ok. I want be sure that if someone paste my JS code on site then code didn't execute if he is not on 'the list'.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it into a variable and override the variable.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. I don't want to do that, I want be sure that someone can't do that.

Comment: Then don't make it a global variable.  Create a self invoking function with private variables. And call the variable value when you want too.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.*` are derived from the value of window.location and are read-only

you can change window.location but that will trigger a redirect

Comment: Thanks. I accepted other question because it has url to reference.

Comment: that is not true, changing those as explained by the marked answer is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the prototype can be overridden. The reality is that, for your use case, you can't prevent your users from executing Javascript code. Even if they could not override a particular property, they can just execute the code block in their console.

Comment: Thats ok for me I think. Single - end user - can try that in console. Important fact is that if someone paste it on site then it won't execute.

Comment: It will execute. You can't trust the code that runs client-side.