# How to get all links on page with javascript navigation?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs

It's easy in classical HTML

`$('a').map(function(){return this.href}).toArray()`

But, if navigation is done via JavaScript with something like:

`<a href='#' onclick='someFn()'>Some link</a>`

It's impossible to know url without executing that `someFn` function, and if you execute it - it won't return url, instead it navigate page away (I don't have control over `someFn` function and don't know what's inside or how to change it).

So, in order to get all N links from page you has to load all of those N pages. This is very slow and inefficient.

**How it can be solved?**

Possible solution - if it would be possible to intercept call to `window.location` - problem solved. You can just click all those links and check value of `window.location` without loading new pages. But I don't know if this is possible to do (I use phantomjs and it seems it can't do it).

**Note**

There are no URL in HTML, even after JavaScript is executed. Yes, in some cases you can use browser emulator to execute JS and then parse HTML generated dynamically in browser. But it's not the case, I use browser emulator (phantomjs) but there are no URL & navigation in HTML even after JS executed, all navigation done in pure JS, with

`<a onclick=tonsOfWeirdBlackBoxFunctionsYouCantChange>`

Comment: What are you trying to archive by that? MAybe there's another way to do that. YOu can, for example, just parse the entire code for links, no matter what context they appear in.

Comment: Basically, I need to visit some pages of site, I can't visit all of them because there are too many. I can detect by URL if it's a page I need to visit or not. I need to get list of URL to analyse and choose which of them to visit (without loading all of it).

Comment: SO there is nothing wrong with just parsing the sourcecode looking for anything that looks like an URL, right? Ignore context. This still doesn't give you URLS that are dynamically created however, thi isn't possible without executiong the javascript.

Comment: No, URLs aren't dynamically created, there are no URLs in HTML even after executing JS, all navigation done in JavaScript, in those black box `someFn` functions. It's impossible to know URL without executing it for every link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to parse an already executed source on a page, you will need to you regex functions to string search for those URL's.

If you are trying to parse code at runtime for locations and save them to an array or something --- every function every object in JavaScript has a `toString` function.

That is --- if you define your `functions` as objects:

```
//Although you should really be using a parameter for this...
//...I'm trying to hold context with your use case.
var redirectToContact = function(){
  window.location = "/contact.html";
}
```

You can `redirectToContact.toString()` and run regex functions on that:

Mabye something like:

```
var url = redirectToContact.toString();
console.log( url.match( 'window.location = "(.*)";' )[1] );
```

Comment: There are no URLs in HTML even after executing JS. And, I don't have access to code and can't change it.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin If you can run the code in your browser you have access to it. At that point you can either run regex functions on a flat file --- or run the the code using a headless browser and intercept HTTP transactions to derive "unknown" URL names.

Comment: """At that point you can either run regex functions on a flat file""" there are 20k+ lines of JS with navigation code put here and there. As for intercepting HTTP calls - thanks, bright idea, I need to check it!

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin You can run regex functions on 20,000 lines of anything in less than a second with a modern processor.

Comment: Yea, but first you has to analyse couple of tens of such sites and write different RE for each of it, I can't even imagine how much time it will take :). Especially if each of it has about 5-15 such functions that are huge and have different logic.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin I see what you're saying. Yea I mean I can't think of too many ways to manually redirect without using `window.location` but mabye interceptting HTTP transactions is your best bet then.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is override the prototype for `window.location`. This SO post explains how that could be done: [Is it possible to override window.location.hostname in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462082/is-it-possible-to-override-window-location-hostname-in-javascript)

However, you have to inject a javascript snippet into each page that runs before any other scripts. I have been working on similar functionality for [the Crawljax web crawler](http://crawljax.com). I use the same kind of [mechanism to detect clickables here](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/pull/368/files#diff-ecac001dc4c1f0378fc2f84538bce96eR1).