# Is there a way to deny location.reload call and href modification?

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this:

```
location.reload = function() { return false }
```

But it seems to be denied as it still reloads the page.

**EDIT**

I do not want to do any harm for a user and lock it into the page. The case where I need it is - integration testing on an existing code base which has `location.reload()` and `location.href = '...'` all over the place.

Comment: Some functions are mutable, this one seems to not be one of them.
Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Locking the user to your page is not a very good idea, I would be surprised if you could coerce the browser into doing that.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204615/programatically-disable-window-location-reload) might be related

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi 
I do not think that OP wants to do that. I think he has an external script that does it and he wants to block it

Comment: You should precise your exact use case, so that it's easier to find a solution.

Comment: Please see edit. I need this for testing.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman thanks. I already tried that. it fails on all browser I have tried

Comment: @Ganesh I see you don't understand the term - testing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

  return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");

};
```

However this is not supported in firefox and opera for that this may be help you

[window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)