# Avoid a third party script's window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a third party script (Adobe DTM, useful to tag management purposes) on my pages, and it is causing the following problem:

I noticed that my pages are being reloaded right after being fully loaded for the first time (in the next load, it doesn't occur anymore), and the blame is on this function, present at one of the scripts loaded by the DTM tag in my HTML.

```
function Ne(Oe, Gc, nc, Ic) {
        if (Oe.targetJSLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        Ic.setCookie(Gc, true, nc);
        window.location.reload(); //in the first page load, this line is always executed
    }
```

It's pretty hard to figure out what is going on the script, once it has more than 5000 lines and it's obfuscated.

I need to prevent that `window.location.reload()` from being executed, but i have the following problems:

1. Once is a third party loaded script (the script tag points to an URL which loads a bunch of other scripts during page load), i can't edit it manually.
2. I can't break the user from reloading the page manually via F5.

I've tried something with the following jQuery code, but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a form to prevent that programatic reload, considering the situations described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `Oe.targetJSLoaded`. Find out what `Oe` is. Try following the call stack starting from the `Ne` function.

For example, the code from Harbor Freight is similar to yours:

```
TNT.a.ge = function (he, ie, Tb, nc, Ub) {
    if (!ie.targetJSLoaded) {
        Ub.setCookie(Tb, true, nc);
        he.location.reload();
    }
};
```

In your function and Harbor Freight's function, we want `targetJSLoaded` to be `true`.

Looking around, we find that `TNT.a.ge` is called by `TNT.a.je`, which is called by an anonymous function like so:

```
TNT.a.je(window, document, b, H, Ub);
```

In `TNT.a.je`, we deduce that `ie.targetJSLoaded` refers to `window._AT.targetJSLoaded`.

Define properties to override `window._AT.targetJSLoaded` to be `true`:

```
function overrideTargetJsLoaded(_AT) {
    Object.defineProperty(_AT, "targetJSLoaded", {
        value: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return _AT;
}

function override_AT() {
    let _AT = overrideTargetJsLoaded({});
    Object.defineProperty(window, "_AT", {
        get: function get_AT() {
            return _AT;
        },
        set: function set_AT(object) {
            _AT = overrideTargetJsLoaded(object);
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

Now, you need to override the `targetJSLoaded` before any other script is executed, so you put the script, which calls the `override_AT` function, before all other scripts on the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your only solution is to modify the script and then replace the DTM tag so that it points to your own version (likely breaking it in the process), or simply stop using Adobe DTM. Any tracking that requires the page to be reloaded to work isn't very well designed.

Answer (score -2):

As long as you don't need to programmatically reload the page anywhere else, you could try overwriting the function.

`window.location.reload = function(){}`

Comment: Thanks Jake!! A question: Can this cause problems on form submits?

Comment: I don't think so, unless your submission callback calls location.reload().

Comment: I've tried it, and faced another problem. The dynamically loaded scripts are being loaded before my custom js. In other words, when i override `window.location.reload`, the page has already been reloaded. Damn!

Comment: Shoot. It looks like it's tricky override it in Firefox and Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204615/programatically-disable-window-location-reload

Comment: Nice and thanks for the alternate solution, but i'll fall in the same problem. All my custom scripts aren't going to make any effect since the DTM ones are being charged before all.